# Appeared this issue during gulp installation

Tags: wordpress, windows, gulp, wordpress-theming

I have followed the [steps][1] on installing in my project.

gulp : The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- gulp -v
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gulp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException



  [1]: https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start
  ```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: gulp : The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gulp
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gulp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 this error is appeared when I am running gulp after installing gulp

Answer (score 0):

Try these two commands

```
npm -g install gulp
```

then

```
npm -g install gulp-cli
```

also try to install locally

```
npm install gulp gulp-cli
```

Comment: npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path D:\usr\local\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
npm ERR! dest D:\usr\local\gulp
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'D:\usr\local\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js' -> 'D:\usr\local\gulp'
npm ERR! File exists: D:\usr\local\gulp
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\umera\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-20T22_26_35_287Z-debug.log

Comment: gulp : The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gulp -v
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gulp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException